# Add remote service GeoNode from local GeoServer that is password protected

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I am trying to add external GeoServer as Remote service in GeoNode.
GeoServer layers published are password protected and there is no provision to mention user and password in GeoNode.
I get following error,
"Harvester Is Still Updating The Available Resources, Please Come Back Later. (0%)"
[image]

Any solution?

By the way, same GeoServer I am able to connect with QGIS as WMS and WFS both.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to include the full error message as text in the body of the Question -- images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same issue.